# Parametros indefinidos en ruta con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un formulario en **Laravel** cuya ruta es **'/{Parámetro1}/{Parámetro2}/{Parámetro3}'** y también he creado una ruta por defecto a la cual se redirecciona al usuario en caso de que escriba cualquier cosa en esos tres parámetros.

Lo que me gustaría saber es cómo redireccionar al usuario a la página por defecto en caso de que escriba más de tres parámetros, ya sean 4, 5, 10, 20, etc.

Estas son las rutas que tengo:

```
// Ruta después de iniciar sesión
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Ruta del botón configuración
Route::resource('configuracion', 'ConfiguracionController');
Route::get('/configuracion/{id}/generate', 'ConfiguracionController@generate');

// Ruta para ir al Formulario
Route::get('/formulario', 'FormularioController@predeterminado');
Route::get('/formulario/{origen?}/{tipoprograma?}', 'FormularioController@procesar');
Route::get('/formulario/{origen?}/{tipoprograma?}/{codigo?}', 'FormularioController@procesar');

// Ruta de la página por defecto
Route::get('/landing', 'LandingController@predeterminado');

// Ruta que lleva a la Landing Page
Route::get('/{origen}/{tipoprograma?}', 'LandingController@procesar');
Route::get('/{origen}/{tipoprograma}/{codigo}', 'LandingController@procesar');

// Ruta que recibe la información del formulario de la landing
Route::post('landing-cep', 'LandingController@store')->name('landing-cep');
```

Para una muestra, cuando ingreso a la página con tres parámetros me aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ingreso con 4 o más parámetros en la URL me aparece un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con Route::fallback capturas cuando el request no coincide con ninguna de las otras rutas, ahí puedes redireccionar a la pagina que quieras https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logré resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Me dirijo al archivo **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**
2. Importo: **use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;**
3. Luego nos vamos al método **render** y lo dejamos así:

   ```
   public function render($request, Exception $exception)
   {
       if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
           return response()->view('ruta de la vista', [], 404);
       }

       return parent::render($request, $exception);
   }
   ```